# java Spring (org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, dependencies

Just started to understand Spring. But there was an error which very strongly slows down process. Before connecting the database, everything worked. After connection there was an error, the database is created but is not filled. I use OpenServer and PHPMyAdmin

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-04T23:56:17.393+03:00 ERROR 24684 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'blogController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'postRepository': Error creating bean with name 'postRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repositorys.PostRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Failed to convert property value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy97 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy97 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repositorys.PostRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Failed to convert property value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy97 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy97 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:605) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy97 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager'; Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy97 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:594) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:608) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:190) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1730) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'jdk.proxy4.$Proxy97 implementing org.hibernate.Session,org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerProxy' to required type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' for property 'entityManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:259) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:589) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 38 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO2lh.png)

## PostRepository.java:

```
package com.example.demo.repositorys;

import com.example.demo.models.Post;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li2K7.png)

## BlogController.java:

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import com.example.demo.models.Post;
import com.example.demo.repositorys.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class BlogController {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @GetMapping("/blog")
    public String blogMain(Model model){
        Iterable<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
        return "blog-main";
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxqHy.png)

## post.java:

```
package com.example.demo.models;


import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private  Long id;
    private  String title, anons, full_text;
    private int views;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAnons() {
        return anons;
    }

    public void setAnons(String anons) {
        this.anons = anons;
    }

    public String getFull_text() {
        return full_text;
    }

    public void setFull_text(String full_text) {
        this.full_text = full_text;
    }

    public int getViews() {
        return views;
    }

    public void setViews(int views) {
        this.views = views;
    }
}
```

## XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I want to create a website with the replenishment of posts from the database

Comment: You are mixing several versions of spring boot ... and since Spring boot 3.X you have to use jakarta api instead of javax ... that means remove the dependency `javax.persistence` from your pomm file... also remove the versions of mysql connector... jakartapersistence-api etc. please show also the application.properteis/application.yml file furthermore you should use constructor injection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change dependencies in your pom.xml.
Remove jkarta.persistence dependecies from your pom.xml.
To be more clear following dependencies are enough for the purpose

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

If the problem persists then
In PostRepository try extending to JPARepository in place of crudRepository.

```
import com.example.demo.models.Post;;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {

}
```

If still there is any error. Do comment.